# Getting image on UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I'm currently making an app where the user takes a photo or select it from an album, then an overlay is placed over the image. The user can then scale, rotate and save the image.

For now, I have 2 xib files. The first one has thumbnails for overlay pictures to choose from.  Clicking on one of them goes to another xib file where I have 2 UIImageViews. One for the overlay and one for the camera. Previously I just used interface builder to set an image at the attributes. But if have 20 overlays, it means I have to use 20 xibs. So I thought the best way is to add pictures through code so I can use this 2nd xib as a template for the overlays. Here's when I'm stuck. When I click on a thumbnail in the 1st xib file, how do tell the 2nd xib file to store an overlay in the UIImageView?

For the camera, I'm using

```
imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

and it works fine. I can even save it to the album. I thought I could use the code below for the overlays but that didn't work.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"char1.png"];
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks very much.

Hakimo

Comment: Do you set the image to the image property of the imageView? Like this: imageView.image = image;

Comment: Yes I have actually. I'm using imageOverlay.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"char1.png"] autorelease]; I had to put it in the viewDidLoad function. But right now, the problem I'm having is that I can only show char1 in the 2nd xib. How should I set other IBAction buttons in the 1st xib to show a different image?

Comment: Hi, hakimo, if you use `imageNamed:` method you should not release or autorelease its result, cause it is already autoreleased. Your application will crash sooner or later if you overrelease objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use xib at all in this situation. Create UIImageView by hands, set its frame and image, add it as a subview to your viewControllers.view . You can have as many UIImageViews as you need. Make an array of them. Your case is obviously misuse of xibs concept. Xibs are usually used when there is need to create some complicated view with many subviews that wouldn't be used in code, like labels, decoration images etc.

```
CGRect frameForImage = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 300);
UIImageView *originalImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frameForImage];
originalImage.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
[self.view addSubview:originalImage];
[originalImage release];

frameForImage.origin.x += 400;
UIImageView *resizedImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frameForImage];
resizedImage.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerWhateverImage"];
[self.view addSubview:resizedImage];
[resizedImage release];
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I think I will use this method instead. But if I use only 1 xib to load all the images, won't that take longer to load?

Comment: If you don't display all images at once, you should load them on demand. Release old, not-visible, and load new that would become visible.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can have two controllers.As you said first one will be static. You can declare the second controller as a class with outlets and ivars. Then you can create instances of that class whenever you you click either of the two controls on the first controller with the appropriate IMageviews (or Images).This is just the concept. I assume you can code this easily.

Comment: Hi Mikayil, I'm not really sure if it's the same but I have created the second controller to act like a class. In the 1st xib, I have 2 IBAction buttons. One to show char1 and the other to show char2. When I press any of the buttons, I want to show the images on the 2nd xib. Right now I can only show one but that's because I'm using the viedDidLoad function on the 2nd xib.